# Particle sliding down frictionless hemisphere on frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

http://web.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/prob87.pdf
http://web.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol87.pdf

The problem and the suggested solution are in the links above. I follow the solutions reasoning except for the very first equation which the rest is based on.

Why do they solve conservation of momentum as $mv_x=MV_x$ instead of $m(v_x-V_x)=MV_x$?

My thought process is that the particles net velocity is the velocity of the particle horizontally Down the hemisphere, minus the hemispheres velocity to the left. Therefore the momentum of the particle is the velocity sum times the mass: $m*(v_x-V_x)$.

The problem arises when they go further with the Equation (1). Because to form Equation 2 they use that the total horizontal velocity of the particle is $v_x+V_x$. This implies that the $v_x$ is not already the sum of the different horizontal components.

I've been looking for this for over two hours. If anyone can spot the mistake in my reasoning it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More Phys.SE posts on [blocks sliding down hemispheres](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=hemisphere+slid*).

Answer (score 1):

This is all to do with the centre of mass motion and the fact that there are no external forces for the hemisphere & particle system.

The velocities are measured **relative to the ground** and as you started with no momentum in the x-direction (other than that due to the infinitesimal impulse) you must end up with no net momentum in that direction.

**Later**
Here is a vector diagram to show how the $\tan \theta$ relationship was found.  The condition is that the velocity of the particle relative to the hemisphere has to be along the inclined surface of the hemisphere.

[image]

Comment: I undersstand that the momentum of the hemisphere is MV_x because it is moving to the left With the velocity V_x relative to rest. But i dont understand that the momentum of the particle is mv_x. The horisontal velocity of the particle relative to rest is (v_x-V_x), right? The minus because it is also moving leftwards to keep up With the hemisphere, as it is moving Down the hemisphere. SO then i would say that its momentum in the x-direction is m*(v_x-V_x)

Comment: This is no different to a bullet being shot out of a rifle.  You would equate the momentum of the bullet travelling in one direction to the momentum of the rifle travelling in the opposite direction.  To evaluate the momentums you would use the velocity of the bullet relative to the ground and the velocity of the rifle relative to the ground.  Would you use a relative velocity anywhere?

Comment: Ok. I have managed to convince myself that the answer makes sence. But also that this answer makes sence. (the response with the momentum in the answer section)http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187342/block-slides-down-a-movable-ramp-2-approaches-yields-different-answer . They are similar problems, but they take different approaches. I cant quite put my finger on what the difference in approaches are. Can you?

Comment: I am confident that the derivation is correct.  I will now go and have a look at this other post.