# Block Sliding on a Wedge: Conservation of Energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation

I have a question regarding a physics problem where a block is sliding down a wedge (which can be seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51551/block-slides-on-smooth-triangular-wedge-kept-on-smooth-floor-find-velocity-of-we)). All of the solutions I've seen to this kind of problem involve the conservation of the **system's** energy, i.e.:

$\frac{1}{2}MV^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=mgh$

I can grasp this idea conceptually, but I was wondering if there was any mathematical way to show it. In my physics textbook, the conservation of energy is demonstrated using the work-KE theorem. First, the work-KE theorem is proven as follows:

$\int_{\mathbf{r_1}}^{\mathbf{r_2}} \mathbf{F_{ext}} d\mathbf{r} = \int_{\mathbf{r_1}}^{\mathbf{r_2}} m \frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt} d \mathbf{r} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} m \frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt} \mathbf{v} dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{m}{2} \frac{d}{dt}(v^2) dt = \frac{1}{2}mv_2^2-\frac{1}{2} mv_1^2=\Delta K$

To my understanding, if working with a system, the substitution $\mathbf{F_{ext}}=m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$ implies that you are dealing with the center of mass. In other words, the work done by the net external force on a system is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of that system's center of mass.

In the case that only conservative forces are acting on the system:

$\int_{\mathbf{r_1}}^{\mathbf{r_2}} \mathbf{F_{con}} d\mathbf{r} = -\Delta U = \Delta K$

Therefore, $\Delta K + \Delta U = 0$, but this is once again for the center of mass. So, if there are only conservative forces acting on this system, I can understand the mechanical energy being conserved **for the center of mass**. I do not understand why the sum of the energies of the system's constituents is conserved. Is there any mathematical way of showing this (from basic principles)? If this explanation is not clear, I can try to provide more details about my thinking. Thank you!

Comment: The substitution F=m dv/dt does not require COM. F and r in dr are both vectors, the theorem as presented in your book implies that F and r in dr points in the same direction. Therefore, since F is defined as the rate of change of momentum in the direction of the force, the direction of v in m dv/dt points in the direction of F, which is in the direction of r in dr as mentioned previously. This is why you can merge the v in dv/dt and v in dr=vdt, into v^2, without having an extra trig term (sin tetha).

Comment: If you consider F to be the (net) force acting on a specific particle in the system, the formula then applies to that particle. However, since they use Fext, which I guess is the net external force acting on the system, the delta-K therefore relates to the change in KE of the system due to the net external force acting on the system.

Comment: The reason why energy is conserved in the system isn't only because only conservative forces are acting on the system. It is because there is no dissipative mechanisms from which energy can be lost. Imagine if the cube sliding down the slope is a filled water balloon instead. Even if I assume no friction between balloon and slope, viscosity of the water as the balloon slides down will dissipate energy, and the final KE gain of the balloon will be lower than the GPE lost.

Comment: Determining the change in sum of constituents' energies due to an external force requires applying the theorem in your book separately to each constituent, while noting that the "external force" in this case include forces applied from other constituents. As an example, your sliding block experience a gravitational pull vertically down, and a reaction force from the slope due to its weight that's angled a to the vertical. The net external force thus pulls it down the slope.

Comment: The slope M has its own vertical gravitational pull, and is pushed by the block towards the left, with a force vector that's equal and opposite to the reaction force on the block. It also has an upward vertical reaction force from the ground. The net force pushes the slope towards the left. Sum up the change in KE, and you should get the same result as if you had done a COM approach, namely that change in GPE of block equals change in KE of block+slope. That sounds like a fun exercise, actually ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response! That makes sense to me (especially the water balloon example), and I will definitely try out both approaches! The book itself implies that this conservation of constituent energies is obvious (it does not do the mathematical proof you suggested). Just to clarify, is this being "obvious" mostly a physical argument (no dissipative forces) than a mathematical argument?

Comment: To be honest, I would say it is "obvious" as well, considering that there is only a straightforward conversion between KE and GPE here. If I'm being technical, a mechanism from which other forms of energy are generated (friction, KE=>heat) or converted (explosion, chemical=>KE+others) does not mean that the energy in the system is not conserved, so long as say the heat energy isn't being taken out of the system.

Comment: Being curious about how to derive in mathematical terms "obvious" physical implications is a really good habit, there's no doubt about that. In this instance for example, a good exercise will be to determine the individual forces acting on each component, and then calculate the rate of change in KE (from a force => acceleration approach) and GPE separately. The results should match what you'll get with a "whole-system" approach, in that slope just gain KE, but loss of GPE is greater than gain in KE of block, and difference equals gain in KE of slope.

Comment: Having said that, a proof based on physical intuition can be regarded as being as rigorous as a purely mathematical one, so long as it is well-reasoned, that's true at the university level as well. So if it were me, I'll do these mathematical derivations as practice, but use physical arguments (symmetry/geometry!!!) as far as possible in exams and in crafting what I regard as good solutions :)